# Ball moving in tube with rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine

Lets say you have a sphere(rigidbody, sphere collider) inside a tube(mesh collider). I want a ball to move in the direction of tube always by applying force on rigidbody.
[image]

My purpose is to simulate the circular gravity, so that ball can fall down back obviously in circular motion. This was the approch i was using to simulate fake circular gravity.
**How can I check which direction of force has to be applied to continue motion following the path of the tube with addforce?**

Answer (score 0):

try applying physics material to your tube to control the ball reaction to the surface of the tube.